# How to correctly route between two similar pathnames in reactjs router

Tags: reactjs

I have setup a router with the below configuration

```
<Router>
    <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
        <Template>
            <Switch>
                <Route path="/search?" component={SearchResult} />
                <Route path="/:id" component={PropertyTemplate} />
            </Switch>
         </Template>
    </Switch>
</Router>
```

I also have a component with the below redirection condition

```
this.state.searchProperties.length > 0 && <Redirect to={{pathname: `/search?query=${this.state.query}`}} />
```

Yet it seems to match  againse pathname `/:id` instead of `/search?`

Comment: Use `/search` instead of `/search?`.

You can specify search as an object parameter, which is nicer than concatenating strings. `<Redirect to={{pathname: '/search', search: this.state.query }} />`

Comment: You could try removing the second `<Switch>....</Switch>` and just setup 3 routes

Comment: adding `search` param and removing `?` from pathname made it work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the '?' int he search route

```
<Route exact path="/search" component={SearchResult} />
```

Comment: still same result

Comment: Add exact to ur search route

Comment: It should have worked without exact
"A <Switch> looks through its children <Route>s and renders the first one that matches the current URL."

Comment: The problem was OP's redirect link. OP was passing the query string parameter as part of `pathname`, which gets URL encoded. As a result the path was not `/search?foo=bar` but `search%3Ffoo%3Dbar`